# How to use parent.postMessage() to send 2 values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send values from ifram to the parent and i found this function

```
parent.postMessage(data,"*")
```

and I am using the code below to get this message

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) { alert(event.data)}
```

my questions is how I can send to 2 values using parent.postMessage??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can send two values using following format.

```
  parent.postMessage("hi there yourself!  the secret response " +
                       "is: rheeeeet!",
                       "*");
```

Comment: That's still only one value, you've added a string together?